# Beautiful Soup extracting title content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Using BeautifulSoup how do you get the content of the title.
Say I was trying to get the "I am a title" below:

h4 class="title" title="I am a title"

I can't see where I'm going wrong, I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

when running:

```
product_name = self.parent.select_one(locator).attrs['title']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><h4 class="title" title="I am a title">test</h4></html>')
>>> soup.find(attrs={'class': 'title'})['title']
'I am a title'
```